# Ubuntu 12.10 is not detecting Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.10

I am having some problems with the installation of Ubuntu 12.10 on my Sony Vaio S laptop.
I currently have Windows 8 installed as UEFI, and I have disabled Secure Boot.

I have downloaded the Secure Ubuntu as described in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), and it is booting from a USB stick just fine.
But whenever I try to install Ubuntu, I am greeted with this window:

[image: Ubuntu not detecting windows]

If I select "Something Else", I can see which partitions Ubuntu has detected:

[image: Ubuntu not detecting windows]

I want to install Ubuntu as a side-by-side installation on the ext4-formatted partition, but I do not have the option to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: This should probably have been asked in AskUbuntu

Comment: This is the 64-bit installer right?

Comment: @Ramhound it is, yes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used that installer. But I would just guess that in the "Something else" dialogue you should select the partitions you want to install ubuntu on, or otherwise create new ones. Then you will probably need to define which partitions should be used as which mountpoint, like one is `/`, another one `/boot` another one `swap` and so on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I have never installed Ubuntu using the manual setting :P

Comment: Elaborate what exactly?

Comment: As I mentioned, I've actually never installed Ubuntu myself. But usually in any Linux you will always need to tell it which partition which mount point is. So it knows where to put the system, where to put the kernel and grub configs, which partition to use as swap space.

Comment: Which of the three (root, boot and swap partition) should point to the efi partition?

Comment: Probably none of them, maybe you have some useful data there. I think thats probably some other bootloader. If you want to put your system to the big ext4, you have to make that one to be `/`. then i would create another small one, like 200MB or so, for `/boot` and another one which is like around 1-4G for `swap`

Comment: And that should preserve the possibility to boot into Windows, right?